# Machine learning in electrical circuit simulation

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, graphs

In the field of VLSI design, and specifically in digital circuits it is common to use electrical simulation software to find signal integrity issues.
I would like to use machine learning instead of running a true electrical simulation to do the same, in order to boost run time (simulations can be very heavy). For example, a NAND logic gate with 2 inputs and 1 output, and on each input there is a noise glitch, and I want to predict the glitch which may occur on the output. A glitch is a waveform represented as a series of voltage and time points. That is, for a given electrical circuit I would like to build a model which can be used to predict an output waveform given input waveforms. Instead of running a (spice) simulation code which calculates results analytically, the output waveform will be predicted or estimated by the model.
Training data can be generated plentifully by running real simulations as many as needed.
I need a direction for types of machine learning algorithms and architectures.
From my research I think using a graph-neural-network (GNN) could be a good direction since an electrical circuit is actually a graph, and it is important to capture the relationships between its elements and other graph properties.
[image: NAND logic gate with glitches on the inputs which cause a glitch on the output]
[image: OR logic gate with glitches on the inputs which cause a glitch on the output]
Thanks!

Comment: if the variance of your process is stable, I guess you can model this as a time series problem like an autoregressive linear model

Comment: Overall you provide too little details, so that it is unlikely that you will get good advice here. A proper problem description would be needed.

Comment: I'll edit my question and try to make it easier to understand, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For waves one usually uses a Sequence Model but for this purpose I think it will probably be the simplest to use a CNN. I am not very familiar with waveforms, but they seem to be similar to standing waves (time independent) or maybe even better as they also have scale invariance. Assuming the number of input waveforms are the same, I would simply stack them side by side and treat the result as any other image and do image classification using a CNN. You can probably also do the analysis by building a multi input CNN, but you probably have to build it from scratch, I don't know any samples of this kind of architecture available online.

Comment: Thanks Serali! this is useful information. What you're suggesting basically, if I understand you correctly, is to use embedding of the input waveforms. In my specific case this is doable since I can represent each waveform as a fixed set of points, and let's assume that the number of input waves if fixed as well. There are two difficulties: CNN can help me predict a scalar or a predefined limited set of output waveforms, or in other words I can do classification with CNN but not a prediction of a full multi-point output waveform.

Comment: The second difficulty is that I need to create a model for each circuit type. If I have different circuits I need a different models, since same set of input waveforms will yield different output waveform for different circuits. What I think can be useful here is to embed the circuit itself in addition to embedding the different waveforms. Thanks indeed for the direction!

Comment: Ok, I apparently misunderstood what you want as an output. I thought the final waveforms are discrete, in the sense that there are a finite number of them. It is probably possible to get such an output as well, but this can probably be defined as a time series prediction. The second difficulty can be addressed as well if you can describe the circuit in terms of numerical and categorical variables. If the order of different types of circuit elements is same for each circuit, this may be possible to achieve.

Comment: The problem with the second difficulty is that it is hard to describe a graph the way you suggest, and there could be crucial difference in the result given the same input waveform if there is a tiny difference between the circuits. Of course not in all cases, but the circuit topology and it's topological properties could have ultimate impact. I've read about graph neural networks (GNNs) and they seem to fit the bill, but I couldn't find code examples or tutorials for novices like me.

Comment: We are moving away from Data Science but isn't circuit topology is a good way to classify the circuits in the first place? Looking at circuit element and their order is more difficult compared to that.

Comment: Circuits can be classified based on topology using different methods and without using machine learning, but even if I have that classification it is still a long way to be able to predict waveforms. There all could be differences between different circuits of the same class. Think of classification of animal photos - even if you can classify between dogs and cats and other animals, and even classify dogs to different breads, you would still have differences between dogs off the same breads. In the same way you will have differences between circuits of the same class.

Comment: I think I should be able to benefit from data science to be able to tackle this problem.